# Issues with JUnit Testing :: assertEquals()

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have the following classes but my jUnit assertEquals() testing is not working. After days of searching and no answer I have decided to post here. Everything in the code seems right but it is still not working.

Contact class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @Column
    private String phone;

    public Contact(){
    }

    public Contact(String name, String address, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this == o){
            return true;
        }
        if(o == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(this.getClass() != o.getClass()){
            return false;
        }

        Contact contact = (Contact)o;

        if(name != contact.getName()){return false;}
        if(address != contact.getAddress()){return false;}
        if(phone != contact.getPhone()){return false;} 

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);

        return result;          
    }       
}
```

Order class:

```
@Entity
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="weekday_recipient")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address", column=@Column(name="weekday_address")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="phone", column=@Column(name="weekday_phone")),
    })
    private Contact weekdayContact;


    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="holiday_recipient")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="address", column=@Column(name="holiday_address")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="phone", column=@Column(name="holiday_phone"))
    })
    private Contact holidayContact;

    public Orders() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Contact getWeekdayContact() {
        return weekdayContact;
    }
    public void setWeekdayContact(Contact weekdayContact) {
        this.weekdayContact = weekdayContact;
    }

    public Contact getHolidayContact() {
        return holidayContact;
    }
    public void setHolidayContact(Contact holidayContact) {
        this.holidayContact = holidayContact; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "orders [WEEKDAY_CONTACT=" + this.getWeekdayContact().toString() +  
         ", HOLIDAY_CONTACT=" + this.getHolidayContact().toString() + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        // self check
        if(this == o){
            return true;
        }
        // null check
        if(o == null){
            return false;
        }
        //type check and cast
        if(getClass() != o.getClass()){
            return false;
        }
        Orders orders = (Orders)o;
        // field comparison

        return Objects.equals(weekdayContact, orders.weekdayContact)
                &&
               Objects.equals(holidayContact, orders.holidayContact);


    }

}
```

Test Class

```
public class Chapter3Test {
    Contact weekdayContact = new Contact("Vienna", "Milkstreet 20", "+336598741");
    Contact holidayContact = new Contact("Cocos Island", "Gulay avenue 85", "+5589632147");
    Orders orders = new Orders();


    EntityManager em = EntitySessionManager.getEntityManager();


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        orders.setWeekdayContact(weekdayContact);
        orders.setHolidayContact(holidayContact);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @Test
    public void createOrders() {

        em.persist(orders);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void retrieveOrders(){
        em = EntitySessionManager.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Orders myOrders = em.find(Orders.class, 2L);

        assertEquals("They are not Equal", myOrders.getWeekdayContact(), orders.getWeekdayContact());
        assertEquals("They are not Equal", myOrders.getHolidayContact(), orders.getHolidayContact());

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

    @After
    public void closeResources(){
        //em.close();
    }

}
```

When i run my test, i get the following results::

```
java.lang.AssertionError: They are not Equal expected: chapter3.Contact<Contact [name=Vienna, address=Milkstreet 20, phone=+336598741]> but was: chapter3.Contact<Contact [name=Vienna, address=Milkstreet 20, phone=+336598741]>
```

You can see that what was expected and what was returned are the same.

Comment: After the facts the question could be seen as DUP to the one I linked to in my answer; but I give you the credit of putting up a really nice, complete question with all the things required to solve the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
private String name;
```

But then within your equals method:

```
if(name != contact.getName()){return false;}
```

You are comparing strings with == resp. != here.

Wrong (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for details). Use `name.equals(contact.getName())` instead!

It is not `asssertEquals()` that is wrong. That method just calls **your** implementation of `equals()`. So when the result is **unexpected**, then **your** implementation must be broken!

And hint: when **comparing** anything (esp. strings) do not trust that **they look the same**. The **one and only** thing that makes objects *equal* ... is the result of the `equals()` method. Anything else does **not** count!